# PHP Query Strings, PHP File

Tags: php, json, query-string

I am running [this plugin](http://xhanch.com/wp-plugin-my-prayer-time/.)

I am wondering, how the data set will look like ? I am new to query stings. I am trying to learn how to put 12 months data in one file. Is there an example of how the dataset look like for query strings because I am unable to find any.

For Example -- **November DataSet**

```
{
 "1" :
      {"fajr":"6:21 AM","sunrise":"7:31 AM","zuhr":"12:53 PM","asr":"3:51 PM","maghrib":"6:14 PM","isha":"7:25 PM","fajri":"6:30 AM","zuhri":"1:30 PM","asri":"4:30 PM","maghribi":"6:24 PM","ishai":"7:45 PM" .....   "fajri":"6:10 AM","zuhri":"12:45 PM","asri":"3:30 PM","maghribi":"5:07 PM","ishai":"7:15 PM"}, ......
 "30" :
      {"fajr":"5:44 AM","sunrise":"6:57 AM","zuhr":"11:58 AM","asr":"2:38 PM","maghrib":"4:57 PM","isha":"6:12 PM","fajri":"6:10 AM","zuhri":"12:45 PM","asri":"3:30 PM","maghribi":"5:07 PM","ishai":"7:15 PM"}
}
```

and **December DataSet**

```
{
 "1" : 
       {"fajr":"5:47 AM","sunrise":"7:01 AM","zuhr":"11:59 AM","asr":"2:38 PM","maghrib":"4:57 PM","isha":"6:11 PM","fajri":"6:15 AM","zuhri":"12:45 PM","asri":"3:30 PM","maghribi":"5:07 PM","ishai":"7:15 PM"}, ..... 
 "31":
       {"fajr":"6:01 AM","sunrise":"7:16 AM","zuhr":"12:09 PM","asr":"2:44 PM","maghrib":"5:02 PM","isha":"6:18 PM","fajri":"6:30 AM","zuhri":"12:45 PM","asri":"3:30 PM","maghribi":"5:12 PM","ishai":"7:15 PM"}
}
```

As of now I have 12 individual files connected to the month. I want to know how can I put them all together under on PHP file and how the call function then works within the file. Like when in the script call for a month or day, how does it identifies in a query string dataset what is being called ...

Comment: Your data seems to be JSON format, you'd better understand JSON a bit. PHP has json_decode() to convert your data to array or object, the rest consider your query logic and implement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Decode the JSON to Array format
2. Merge the multiple month array content into single array
3. Optional. Save the result to file in JSON format

Task 1:
Convert the JSON string to array by json_decode($stringString, true /* True for return array, false for Object */ );

Task 2:
Loop each of the months, every data (each day) will be store into another array with the key in date format. Such as '2013-12-01'.

Task 3:
Save the array in JSON format file. file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($finalArray) )

Something like that (For task 2)

```
<?
$finalArray = array();
//each month
foreach( $monthsJsonString as $month => $monthJson ){
    $monthData = json_decode($monthJson, true);
    //loop days
    foreach( $monthData as $day => $dayData){
        $dateStr = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
        $finalArray[ $dateStr ] = $dayData
    }
}

/*
//output
array(
    '2013-11-01'=>array(
        'fajr'=>'6:21 AM',
        'sunrise'=>'7:31 AM',
        ...
        'ishai'=>'7:15 PM'
    ),
    '2013-11-02'=>array(
        'fajr'=>'6:21 AM',
        'sunrise'=>'7:31 AM',
        ...
        'ishai'=>'7:15 PM'
    ),
    ...
    '2013-12-31'=>array(
        'fajr'=>'6:21 AM',
        'sunrise'=>'7:31 AM',
        ...
        'ishai'=>'7:15 PM'
    )
)
*/
?>
```